# Android Put intent from onclick of button created programmatically - Activity Not Found Exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I have to put intent to a service from on click of a button, where the whole layout is created programmatically.
I have checked all answers for 'Android content activity not found exception' and have tried all answers. But still the problem persists. I have used try catch block, still the problem exists.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        db = new DBOperation(this);
        document = getIntent().getStringExtra("document_id");
        getAlldataList=db.getPartiesReport(db);
        LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout rootView1 = new LinearLayout(this);
//        RelativeLayout rootView2 = new RelativeLayout(this);

        Button update1 = new Button(this);
        update1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        update1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        update1.setText("UPDATE");

        update1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffa500"));
        update1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) update1.getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(20, 20, 20, 10);
        update1.setLayoutParams(params);
        update1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i < poslist.size(); i++) {
//

//                  SQLiteDatabase base3 = db.getWritableDatabase();
//                    base3.delete(UPDATEPARTIES1, null, null);
//                    System.out.println("Parties DB Deleted");
                    SQLiteDatabase db7 = db.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues values5= new ContentValues();
                    values5.put(DBManager.TableInfo.KEYID, ID1);
                    values5.put(DBManager.TableInfo.DOCUMENT, document);
                    values5.put(DBManager.TableInfo.ATTENDANCE,attendancelist.get(i));
                    values5.put(DBManager.TableInfo.EMAILNEW, emaillist.get(i));
                    values5.put(DBManager.TableInfo.PARTYTYPE,partytypelist.get(i) );
                    values5.put(DBManager.TableInfo.BIOMETRIC,biometriclist.get(i));
                    values5.put(DBManager.TableInfo.KEY_LOGIN_USER,username2);
                    String condition5 = DBManager.TableInfo.DOCUMENT + " =?";
                    Cursor cursor5 = db7.query(DBManager.TableInfo.UPDATEPARTIES1, null, condition5, new String[]{DBManager.TableInfo.ATTENDANCE}, null, null, null);
                    long status5 = db7.insert(DBManager.TableInfo.UPDATEPARTIES1, null, values5);
                    System.out.println( "Parties insert : " + status5);
                    cursor5.close();
                    db7.close();
                }

                itemlist.clear();
                poslist.clear();
                IDlist.clear();
                attendancelist.clear();
                partytypelist.clear();
                emaillist.clear();
                biometriclist.clear();
                System.out.println("Poslist:" + poslist.size());
                System.out.println("itemlist:" + itemlist.size());
                System.out.println("IDlist:" + IDlist.size());
                Intent i1=new Intent(anulom.executioner5.com3.anulom.newstatusinfo.this,SendPartyReport.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

[What I need is to do put a intent to a service SENDPARTYREPORT from the onclick listener of  button UPDATE 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaZHd.png)

Comment: Is the activity 'SendPartyReport' in the manifest?

Comment: have you declared this activity in manifest file

Comment: Yes  <service
            android:name="anulom.executioner5.com3.anulom.services.SendPartyReport"
            android:enabled="true">
           
        </service>

Comment: This is newstatusinfo in manifest.      <activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:name="anulom.executioner5.com3.anulom.newstatusinfo"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: 'SendP‌​artyReport' is service then why startActivity();

Comment: All other services have been started the same way, they are working fine.

Comment: Sorry.. Yes we have used start activity... Thanks... I will get back after trying..

Comment: Thank you Anil. It is working fine now....!!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to call

```
startService(i1);
```

instead of

```
startActivity(i1);
```

The exception occurs because you tried to start an Activity and not a Service. If i unterstand you correct that the SendPartyReport is a Service then you will have to use the startService method.

Greetings